Does Jesus' lack of knowledge regarding the time of the second coming challenge the omniscience of God?
Matthew 21:36 says that only the Father shall know the time at which Jesus shall return to the earth. Since Jesus is divine and the nature of God is omniscient, does this pose a challenge to the omniscience of God?

"But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the son, but only the Father."


Are you after an exegetical answer or a theological answer?

...Both I think? Exegetical in the sense that this concept is rather unique to this verse but also theological considering implications on the nature of Christ. Saw elsewhere that many consider Jesus not to be omniscient?

This question seems already to have answers: see eg here.

Ultimately, I don't think there's too much to say exegetically from this passage - it simply presents Jesus's statement. That's why I think this is mainly a question of systematic theology, and those questions belong on [christianity.se] instead.

This question is similar to: What does it mean that the Son did not know the hour of his return in Matthew 24:36 // Mark 13:32?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@blaepic. Jesus' admission of his ignorance show he is not the God he himself worships. Delusive reasoning may fool some, but the wise will discern.

@AlexBalilo Jesus ignorance relates to His abeyance as a humble human servant: (Phillipians 2:5-11).  Each nature (human and divine) retaining their own respective attributes.

"Ignorance" is a bit harsh.  Just because you don't know something doesn't make you ignorant, or uninformed.

The idea that anyone, including Jesus, would or could "choose" to forget something they previously knew, or "choose" to not know something that they could have chosen to know is nonsensical.

Why would Jesus even make this comment?  Perhaps because he knew that in times to come, people would come to wrongly believe that he was all knowing.  He knew a lot but not everything.  Only God knows everything.  But doesn't God share all His knowledge with His own son?  Evidently not.

@Cork88. Jesus remained a servant even after his ascension to heaven. There's nothing recorded in the bible that says that "this Jesus said as a human and this he said as the God". A servant is not greater than his master.

@AlexBalilo Study the topic of abeyance and realize that Jesus is the Word who is also God in John 1.  The amount of theological and hermeneutical gymnastics that you would be performing here are quite telling.  Unitarianism had no biblical hoot hold anywhere in scripture.

@Cork88. Who is the God that the word was with? Jesus and his Father count as 2 not 1.

@AlexBalilo 2 divine persons, (was with God, in Greek means “face to face”) who are both the same God.  Your issue here is with assuming God must equal One Person.  John 1:1-18 makes it clear there is One God, two persons who are the same God, and the Word was made flesh (I.e.: Human) and the Father (who is God) was never made a man, Jesus was.  (Cf. 1 John 4:2).

@Cork88. Jesus counted himself and the Father as 2 persons, John 8:17. If these two are face to face how can they be the same God?. After the word became flesh and was resurrected, he still has his God and still is a servant of his God after his resurrection. God is not a servant.

@AlexBalilo I don’t think you understand Jesus’ role to become like one of us in order to redeem us, He willingly humbled Himself unto death and submitted to His Fathers will for the sake of redemption, Jesus and the Father are the same God, separate persons.  Jesus is equal with God (Phillipians 2, John 5).

@Cork88. I don't think you understand that the God of the bible is not begotten, God has no Father. He is the Father. Jesus whom you believe is also God himself said that the Father is greater than him. He remained a servant after his resurrection. Equivocating vocabulary to accommodate a multi - person God does not stand scrutiny..

@AlexBalilo Again, you ignore texts like Phillipians 2 and John 5, Jesus is equated with God.  Being a servant during and even if after His resurrection does not necessitate inferiority.  Jesus is nowhere called an Angel, or just a Man.  He is called “the Heavenly Man” (1 Corinthians 15) and He is called God (John 1:1, 20:28).  It is you who also don’t understand that “begotten” in the Greek is the word “monogenes” meaning: “unique in its kind”.  Jesus is begotten in that sense, not made.  See the book: “Father, Son and Spirit: The Trinity and John's Gospel (New Studies in Biblical Theology)”.

@Cork88. Again you ignore what Jesus your God said. John 14:28 revelation 3:12, and what the disciples have said Acts 4..  Acts 15:28. The God of the bible is not begotten. The God of the bible has no Father, He is the Father. The multi-person doctrine of God is self contradictory.

@AlexBalilo You ignore large swaths of scripture, don’t even bother me with that.

@Cork88. You ignore your God, Jesus, who said his Father is greater than all, and greater than him.

@AlexBalilo Jesus’ submitted to His Father’s will for the role of redemption and was temporarily made a little lower than the angels for the suffering of death.  He is still God (John 1:1-14).  See the book: “A Definitive Look at Oneness Theology: In the Light of Biblical Trinitarianism” by Edward L. Dalcour Ph.D. (Author)

@Cork88.. No amount of sophistry will put sense in the doctrine you are trying to advance. It's clear that your God Jesus said that the Father is greater than all, including him. That is why he is still a servant after his ascension to heaven.. The God of Jesus does not submit to anybody. God has no Father. He is the Father.

@AlexBalilo Do you believe God is a personal agent/being?

@Cork88. Do you believe God is a personal agent/being?

@AlexBalilo Stop deflecting, I asked you first.

@Cork88. God is a person and God is also a being. Now you answer my question.

@AlexBalilo Okay if you take that position then you concede that “the Word” is a person, because “the Word” is also called God, and God the Father never came in the flesh, only Jesus did.  So your oneness position falls apart based on your view of God.

@Cork88. Tha word that became flesh has a God that is greater than him. That's straight from your God's (Jesus) mouth. Your God the Word changed from Word to flesh. The God of Jesus does not change.. Who is this God of yours that you are trying to explain with delusive reasoning? Jesus God is Greater than all, including Jesus. Jesus' God has no Father He is the Father

The question of the lack of knowledge of Jesus concerning the moment of the second coming is a complex subject that raises hermeneutical and theological issues. By examining the Scriptures, in particular the Gospel of Mark (13:32), where Jesus declares that only the Father knows the day and time of his return, we are led to reflect on the nature of divine omniscience. This text is often at the heart of debates about the divinity of Jesus and his incarnation. To answer the question posed, we will explore two main perspectives: hermeneutical and theological.
A. Hermeneutical Perspective

Scriptural Background
The passage from Mark 13:32 is fundamental to understand Jesus' position on knowing the moment of his return. Jesus said: "But as for that day or that hour, no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father.’’ This statement raises questions about the nature of the knowledge of Jesus and his relationship to omniscience.
The exegetes agree that this statement must be interpreted in the context of the incarnation. By becoming man, Jesus chose to live within the limits of human experience. This implies a certain self-limitation of his divine knowledge in order to fulfill his earthly mission. This hermeneutical perspective emphasizes that Jesus' words should not be understood as a negation of his divinity, but rather as an expression of his humanity.


2. Interpretation of Texts The interpretation of biblical texts is crucial to understand the implications of Jesus' statement.
Theologians, such as Karl Barth and Thomas Aquinas, have approached
this issue by emphasizing that the incarnation does not mean that
Jesus has ceased to be God. On the contrary, he has chosen to live
fully as a man, with all the limitations that this implies. This
self-limitation can be perceived as an act of humility and submission
to the will of the Father. Thus, the limited knowledge of Jesus
concerning the moment of his return is not a contradiction with divine
omniscience, but an aspect of the mystery of the incarnation. This
leads us to consider the way in which God reveals himself to humanity
through Christ.

B. Theological Perspective

1. Nature of the Incarnation The doctrine of the incarnation is essential to understand the relationship between Jesus and the
omniscience of God. According to this doctrine, Jesus is both fully
God and fully man. In his humanity, he chose not to exercise certain
divine attributes, including omniscience, in order to live an
authentic human experience. This duality of nature poses a theological
challenge, because it implies that Jesus, as a man, really lived
limitations. However, this does not diminish his divinity in any way.
On the contrary, it highlights the depth of his identification with
humanity and his commitment to the salvific mission.
2. Omniscience of God Christian theology affirms that God is omniscient, which means that he knows everything, including the moment
of the second coming. The limitation of the knowledge of Jesus does
not call into question this omniscience, but rather emphasizes the
mystery of the incarnation. God, as the Father, holds a perfect and
complete knowledge of history and the future. This distinction between
the divine knowledge and the human knowledge of Jesus is crucial.
Jesus, in his role as mediator, chose to live a human experience,
which includes elements of uncertainty and dependence on the Father.
This reinforces the idea that the knowledge of Jesus is fully human in
his incarnation, while being rooted in his divine nature.
3. Divine Plan The notion of a divine plan is also relevant in this discussion. The progressive revelation of God throughout the
history of salvation implies that certain truths are revealed at the
appropriate time. The fact that Jesus does not know the time of his
return can be understood as an integral part of this divine plan. This
suggests that the knowledge of God is reserved for the Father for
reasons beyond our human understanding. This perspective emphasizes
the importance of trust and faith in God's revelation. Believers are
called to live in expectation and hope, knowing that the moment of the
second coming is in the hands of God.

Conclusion
In conclusion, Jesus' lack of knowledge regarding the moment of the second coming does not call into question God's omniscience, but rather illustrates the mystery of the incarnation. Jesus chose to live his humanity to the fullest, which implies limitations in knowledge. This invites us to a deeper reflection on the nature of God and revelation in the history of salvation.
The tension between the humanity of Jesus and his divinity is a fundamental aspect of the Christian faith. It reminds us that God, in his love, chose to incarnate to save us while remaining sovereign and omniscient. This understanding enriches our relationship with God and pushes us to live in faith, hope and trust in His perfect plan.

My edit is to improve formatting for this scholarly answer. Just to clarify: It appears you are quoting from a source but no reference is given to that. Whether the source is that of another scholar, or is entirely your own work, this hermeneutic site appreciates a link or book reference. However, if you are not lifting quotes from anywhere, my formatting - giving block quote indentations - needs to be removed. I hope I have not made a mistake here, and would seek your pardon if I have! Just roll back what is not suitable.

Very good and comprehensive answer.

Read my answer to
What does it mean that the Word became flesh?.
The key points are:

Instead, he gave up his divine privileges; he took the humble position of a slave and was born as a human being.
— Philippians 2:7 (NLT):


17 Wherefore in all things it behoved him to be made like unto his brethren, that he might be a merciful and faithful high priest in things pertaining to God, to make reconciliation for the sins of the people.
18 For in that he himself hath suffered being tempted, he is able to succour them that are tempted.
— Hebrews 2:17,18

Verse 17 can be expressed in many ways, but they all express the same idea:

(KJV) made like unto his brethren.
(NLT) made in every respect like us.
(NIV) fully human in every way.
(CSB) like his brothers and sisters in every way.
(NET) like his brothers and sisters in every respect

For a brief time, Jesus gave up his divine power and abilities and became a mortal physical human being.
He was still "God", the person, with his original personality, character, and knowledge of what he used to be.
But his only access to supernatural power was through God's holy spirit, and that access to the Father was no different from what is now available to all mortal humans.
As a human being, Jesus was capable of being tempted to sin, and there was much that he no longer knew (though he could have asked) and much that he was no longer capable of doing under his own power.
Compare the situation (at a very superficial, non-religious level) with George W. Bush or Barack Obama.

Each of them was fully President, with all the power that position provides.
After their terms ended, each willingly gave up that power and became a normal citizen.
Each is still called "Mr. President", retaining all the honour and government protection that comes with the position.
Being a fully "normal citizen", each of them has no official position or power in the government (though they can and do, communicate and advise the current President).

Unlike with presidents though, Jesus's original divine power and abilities were restored.
(Comparisons to President Trump are not welcome.)

Your contradicting yourself. You first stated correctly I might add, "Instead, he gave up his divine privileges; he took the humble position of a slave and was born as a human being.
— Philippians 2:7 (NLT):" Then you stated: "For a brief time, Jesus gave up his divine nature and became a mortal physical human being." One cannot give up their nature. Jesus is the only person to have two natures. One on His mother's side where Jesus referred to Himself as the "Son of Man/human" And one on His Father's side where Jesus referred to Himself as the "Son of God/deity."

@Mr.Bond says "Your contradicting yourself." — I don't see a contradiction between those two statements. Perhaps the confusion is with the word "nature"? By that, I meant the supernatural attributes that are possessed by God but not by Man. He temporarily surrendered everything that made him God. (As opposed to everything that makes him "God" as opposed to a hypothetical other "god".) Compare with: if Elon Musk gave away all his possessions, had plastic surgery, and lived anonymously in a slum in South Africa, he'd still be Elon Musk, but lacking everything people associate with Elon Musk.

The Greek word for "nature" is physis and it refers to the sum of innate properties and powers by which one person differs from others. It is used in the Bible exactly the same way as it is used in trinitarian theology when we say there is ONE GOD who's nature (that which distinguishes Him from all that is not God) is manifest in three persons (that by which the identity is expressed). At Phil 2:6, Jesus already existed as God and at vs7 He emptied Himself, (How?) by becoming a bond-servant/man. As a man He relinquishes His divine privileges to fully embrace His human nature.

@Mr.Bond, I too was referring to something like "that which distinguishes Him from all that is not God". Once he relinquished it, he was indistinguishable from a human being (while retaining his personality and character). But I've now changed it to "power and abilities".

Answer
Jesus’ lack of knowledge regarding the time of the second coming does not challenge the omniscience of God.
If there is a problem, it could be in our understanding.
Explanation
I keep out any of my philosophical inclinations. I leave all the theories and creeds behind. I focus on the Scripture.
When talking about Jesus, the Scripture states:

“having taken the form (morphe) of a servant” (Phlp 2:7; BibleHub).

History states that Jesus was 100% a human being. Hardly people deny this. So, this much is sure.
Thus, morphe of a servant means a human being.
But there is more in the above statement. He actively “took” the form of a human being.
No human has ever taken a form of something at his volition before birth. We are all simply born as human beings unaware of any wishes or ambitions on our part before birth.
Only a Person who existed before can “take” a form He wants!
Do we have any such information like that?
Yes, here it is:

“Christ Jesus who existing in the form (morphe) of God” (Phlp 2:6;
BibleHub).

Scripture reveals that Jesus Christ was pre-existing before His incarnation as God.
If morphe of servant is 100% human being, then morphe of God is 100% God. This is an undeniable logical conclusion.
Morphe cannot mean two different things in the same place!
Other Scripture verses prove the same thing:

“The Word was God” (John 1:1)


“And Thomas answered and said to Him, My Lord and my God!” (John
20:28).

So, things are clear to me now. Jesus as the Word existed before His incarnation as God Himself but later, as the Almighty God He took upon Himself the low form of a physical human being.
But what happened in between?

“not considered the to-be-equal-with-God something to be grasped
(something to be held on) but EMPTIED Himself” (Phlp 2:6-7;
BibleHub).

Who can “empty” himself?
Can a human being empty himself? No.
Can a mighty lion empty itself? No.
Can a tiny ant empty itself? No.
Only an Almighty God can empty Himself! And that is exactly what the Almighty God did and He became a human being!
What did He empty Himself of?
“Empty” is “κενόω” (kenoō) in Greek. BibleHub gives the following explanation under the heading “Usage”:

“The verb κενόω primarily means "to empty" or "to make void." In the
New Testament, it is often used metaphorically to describe the act of
making something of no effect or rendering it powerless. It can also
imply the act of divesting oneself of status or privilege.”
(https://biblehub.com/greek/2758.htm)

The same Greek word is used in these verses: “void” (Rom 4:14), “made of none effect” (1 Cor 1:17), “void” (1 Cor 9:15), and “in vain” (2 Cor 9:3).
The word clearly shows that God forsook all the glory, power, status and privileges of Godhead.
The same word does not refer to any “concealment” or “putting on something above an existing something”, “union of 2 things” etc. It simply means “putting off what was before”.
So, when Jesus Christ walked on the earth as a man, He was 100% a human being without any attributes of a powerful God. He hungered, felt thirsty and got tired. Anybody could hurt Him (in fact they killed Him). He prayed to His Father God.
Please don’t misunderstand: He is the same Person who was God. So, in that sense, Jesus is God but without the glory and power of Godhead.
Scripture confirms:

“Jesus Christ, the same (Person) yesterday and today and forever” (Heb
13:8).

As a 100% human, Jesus said:

“I am able to do nothing from Myself; just as I hear, I judge; and
My judgment is just, for I do not seek My will, but the will of the
One sending Me, the Father” (John 5:30).

As a 100% human without Godly power, Jesus said:

“But concerning that day and the hour, no one knows, not the angels,
those in Heaven, nor the Son, except the Father” (Mar 13:32).

So how did Jesus do the mighty things?
Jesus Himself answers:

“And Jesus lifted His eyes upward and said, Father, I thank You that
You heard Me. And I know that You always hear Me” (John 11:41-42).


“…I cast out the demons by the Spirit of God…” (Mat 12:28).

So, Jesus was able to do many mighty miraculous acts through the help of God the Father.
Yes, Jesus did everything through His Father who was ever ready to hear and help His Son.
Does Jesus know the day and hour now?
Yes, He knows. After His resurrection, He declared:

“All authority in Heaven and on earth was given to Me” (Mat
28:18).

A Person who has started wielding ALL authority in Heaven and on earth (as before the incarnation) will definitely know the day and hour of His second coming.

“Because you kept the Word of My patience, I also will keep you out of
the hour of trial which is going to come on all the habitable world in order to try those dwelling on the earth” (Rev 3:10).

This is talking about the Great Tribulation that is to come at the end of the world. How can Jesus protect His followers if He doesn’t know when that “hour” is coming?
So, He knows now!
Conclusion
“with God all things are possible” (Mat 19:26).
Problem is with the limitations of human understanding.

Jesus remained a servant after his ascension to heaven. A servant is not greater than or equal to this master. There's nothing recorded in the bible that say that "this Jesus said as a human and this he said as the God".

These are all your personal opinions. Jesus considered Himself different from prophets, apostles and other such servants including Moses (Mat 21:36, Heb 3:5-6). He is the Son of God. If a son can be a servant of his father, then Jesus is a servant (pais not doulos) of God. He is the monogenes Son of God (John 3:18). If you want to downgrade Him into a slave (dolous) after the ascension, you have every freedom to do so. But that is not Scriptural.

You said a servant cannot be equal to his master. But Jesus is greater than you and He said a servant is not greater than his master but definitely he can become equal to his master (Mat 10:25). Grasp this if you can: among humanity, a servant is a human and his master is also a human (same nature), though they may differ in authority. So a monogenes Son of God is God in nature just as His Father is God in nature. But Father is greater in authority.

Jesus was still a servant of God after his ascension. He still was not equal to his God after his ascension. God is not a servant.

Thanks for the conversation.

Yes and no. Humanly he was "in every way"  one of us. So humanly, he didn't know, yet in his divinity, he knew.

14 Since the children have flesh and blood, he too shared in their humanity so that by his death he might break the power of him who holds the power of death--that is, the devil--
... 17 For this reason he had to be made like them, fully human in every way, in order that he might become a merciful and faithful high priest in service to God, and that he might make atonement for the sins of the people. [Heb 2:14, 17 NIV]

In the boat, he slept as humans do and was unaware of the storm. Yet, when awoken, he got up and rebuked the storm as only God can do.

37 And a great windstorm arose, and the waves beat into the boat, so that it was already filling. 38 But He was in the stern, asleep on a pillow. And they awoke Him and said to Him, "Teacher, do You not care that we are perishing?" 39 Then He arose and rebuked the wind, and said to the sea, "Peace, be still!" And the wind ceased and there was a great calm. [Mar 4:37-39 NKJV]

It's beyond all of us!

116 And without controversy great is the mystery of godliness: God was manifested in the flesh, Justified in the Spirit, Seen by angels, Preached among the Gentiles, Believed on in the world, Received up in glory. [1Ti 3:16 NKJV]


This is where the doctrine of the Hypostatic Union comes in. Whithout a good understanding of this doctrine, confusions are bound to occur.
Hypostatic union (from the Greek: ὑπόστασις hypóstasis, 'person, subsistence') is a technical term in Christian theology employed in mainstream Christology to describe the union of Christ's humanity and divinity in one hypostasis, or individual personhood.
The hypostatic union of His divine and human natures can be seen in John 1:1-14; Philippians 2:6-11; Romans 1:2-5; 9:5; 1 Timothy 3:16; Hebrews 2:14; 1 John 1:1-3.
Jesus is God-Man.

“For what the law could not do, in that it was weak through the flesh, God sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh, and for sin, condemned sin in the flesh:” (Rom 8:3, KJV)


“Who, being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be equal with God: But made himself of no reputation, and took upon him the form of a servant, and was made in the likeness of men:” (Php 2:6-7, KJV)

When he incarnated, he put on the likeness of sinful flesh or he was made in the likeness of men.
God became man wihout losing his godness. His humanity that he put on operated on earth. We see that implied in Jn.17:5.
When Jesus made the statement in Matt.24:36, it was his humanity that was in operation.
Does Jesus' lack of knowledge regarding the time of the second coming challenge the omniscience of God?
It's like asking this: Does the taste of fruit in the cup challenge the insipid taste of water?
Inspite of Jesus's full humanity expressed, God the Father remained God. Matt 24:36 says,

“But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven, but my Father only.” (Mat 24:36, KJV)

The Father who is still divine knows that day and the hour showing his omniscience.
God the Father's omniscience was not impeded by Jesus's humanity.
